# How to compare meaningful level of a set of phrase that describe same concept in NLP?

Tags: python, nlp

I have two terms "vehicle" and "motor vehicle". Are there any way to compare the meaningfulness level or ambiguity level of these two in NLP? The outcome should be that "motor vehicle" is more meaningful than "vehicle" or "vehicle" is more ambiguous than "motor vehicle". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you ask is very broad (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity)) but here are some hints for starting points:

1. [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/)
2. [Word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding): [word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec), [Glove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GloVe_(machine_learning))

The meaning difference you are looking into is quite peculiar so I suggest starting with WordNet (there are WordNets for other languages as well).
The code that uses WordNet to *calculate* meaning differences using WordNet you can find [here](https://github.com/chanddu/Sentence-similarity-based-on-Semantic-nets-and-Corpus-Statistics-).

Good framework to start an NLP journey is [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Thank you, I have used wordnet for finding synsets or similarity. But I want something like a scoring method to choose the most specific meaning in a set of general meaning words.

Comment: Is it in wordnet but I haven't discovered yet? Can you help me with a more specific tool?

Comment: WordNet is your friend then - you can check hypernym / hyponym paths to ensure the specificity of  meaning.

Comment: And you can always rank words by similarity between each other calculated using the code link provided above if you are looking for an easy interface.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I tried but I didnt have enough reputation to vote up. But many thanks.