# Creating text-clusters that contain similar text

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-analysis, unsupervised-learning

Recently I had worked on image clustering which found similar images and grouped them together. I had used python's `skimage` module to calculate SSIM and then cluster all images based on some threshold that was decided.

I want to do similar for the text. I want to create automatic clusters containing similar text. For example, cluster-1 could have all text that represents working mothers, cluster-2 could have all text representing people talking about food and so on. I understand this has to be unsupervised learning. Do we have similar python module's that could help achieve this task? I also checked out google's tensorflow to see if I could get something from it but did not find anything relating to text clustering in its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways you can approach the task. In most cases the clustering algorithms are very similar to image clustering but what you need to define is the distance metric - in this case [semantic similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity) metric of some kind.

For this purpose you can use the approaches I list in another [question around the topic of semantic similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800803/how-to-compare-meaningful-level-of-a-set-of-phrase-that-describe-same-concept-in/50801031?noredirect=1) (even if a bit more detailed).

The one additional approach worth mentioning is 'automatic clustering' provided by [topical modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) tools like [LSA](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/latent-semantic-indexing-1.html) which you can run [fairly easy](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html#latent-semantic-analysis) using `gensim` package.

Comment: Is there any `doc/tutorial` that could help me create a small setup for automatic text clustering using `gensim`?

Comment: Try the fairly easy link ;)

Comment: Tried but getting error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'corpora'`, though I have installed `gensim`

Comment: Do you use the same version of `gensim` as in the tutorial? There were some recent changes...